# PathML for image processing in Python, Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, java, image-processing, error-handling, anaconda

I am reaching out regarding the installation of Pathml on both my Mac and windows, I followed these instructions (https://openbase.com/python/pathml/documentation) exactly but whenever I try to import ‘Pathml’ into my Jupyter Lab cell, it give me the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pathml'

I would appreciate any sort of help

Tried installing more Java stuff but no way

Comment: Did you use the `pip` command that goes with the Python that you use in your notebook? Each Python package installation is exclusive to the one Python you installed with.

Comment: @AbdullahErikat the [official documentation](https://github.com/Dana-Farber-AIOS/pathml#installation) explains different approaches for installing this library, can you please specify which one are you following? have you installed the dependencies? please provide more details.

Comment: Try running in a cell in your notebook `%pip install pathml`, restarting the kernel, and then importing. The magic command will install to the environment backing your notebook.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes i did use Pip, I followed the official documentation till the last command which is 'Pip install Pathml' it starts downloading then it gives this error (see below comment). Thank you for your help guys

Comment: The error when i run this on Mac terminal (i tried anaconda too) ' in ext_modules
          from numpy import get_include
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(pathml) abdullaherikat@Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % "

Comment: @BilalI did follow that documentation indeed

Comment: When you use the `pip` command, you need to make sure it is the one that belongs to the installation of Python that you use in your notebook. It is likely that a simple `pip install ...` will install for a different Python than the one in your notebook. Do as @Wayne suggested above, installing it from within your notebook.

Comment: @Wayne I just tried this, it seems to be getting somewhere, because it downloaded loads of stuff and added it to the env, but then I got this error although I do Openslide downloaded, will try now to see if I missed something,, The error ,  ModuleNotFoundError: Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib.  Is OpenSlide installed correctly?  https://openslide.org/api/python/#installing

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thank you for the tip, will keep that in mind, will carry on now, really appreciate it, will see what I can do now

Comment: @Wayne I made sure openside is downloaded correctly and when I import it , it works , but when I import Pathml is still get this error      ModuleNotFoundError: Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib.  Is OpenSlide installed correctly?  https://openslide.org/api/python/#installing

Comment: I have no idea what point you are at now. From those directions you link, it looks like OpenSlide is particularly tricky to install on platforms. You'll have to do what it says. Looks like before you can do you need 'OpenSlide from MacPorts'. Only then will you be able to move on to trying to install OpenSlide Python. But it sounds like maybe you did that. I think you probably need to look around for information on `Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib` in regards to Pathml or open a new question. You seem to have addressed the original one and made some progress. Maybe use pip to uninstall and ...

Comment: <continued> reinstall pathml now that openslide is installed. I don't know. There's probably better information out there. Point is you addressed your original question.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you Wayn will try some few things, appreciate the help :)

Comment: All good. to get over the 'Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib, was to use conda command from a Docker terminal using this command . <<conda install -c conda-forge openslide>> followed by Pip install openslide-python. Thank you for everything :) :) :)